# How can I print hindi words by combining characters using fpdf in python?

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, fpdf

I want to display proper characters.
Currently I am using this code.

```py
pdf.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
pdf.set_font('gargi', '', 13.5)
pdf.set_xy(0, y)
pdf.multi_cell(h=5.0, align='C', w=self.pdf_width, txt='रामस्वरुप')
```

[image]

I want to print text as follows

[image]

I have tried with Unicode fonts still output is same. For some fonts, I get garbage text.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, python 3, fpdf version 1.7.2.

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem(s) you want to fix. Is it the missing ligatures? That the text is outside/inside the box? What kind of garbage characters do you see for which input?

Comment: A font is not the only thing that enables you to format text content. The underlying engine needs to support the rules for character  combination. Perhaps the formatter you have selected does not. No choice of font will fix that

Comment: There is currently work going on to add Harfbuzz support to fpdf2. This would add opentype complex font rendering to fpdf.

Answer (score 0):

`fpdf` does not seem to fully support hindi language writing. I managed to write hindi words to pdf by the use of docx.
So, at first we need to write the hindi words in docx using `python-docx` module then we can convert the docx to pdf using `docx2pdf` module.

Install using:

```
pip install python-docx docx2pdf
```

Code:

```
import os, docx
from docx2pdf import convert

document = docx.Document()
document.add_paragraph('रामस्वरुप')
document.save(f'test.docx')  #save to test.docx file

convert("test.docx")  #convert test.docx to test.pdf

os.remove('test.docx')  #remove docx file
```

This will generate the pdf with the same first name as docx file, so `test.pdf` will be generated.